# Accessing parent methods of generic enum which implements interface

Tags: java, generics, interface, enums

Ok I am currently defining generic enum arguments as follows:

```
public interface MyInterface
{
    public int GetValue ( );
}

public enum MyEnum implements MyInterface
{
    value1(1), value2(2);

    int myvalue;

    MyEnum ( int value )
    {
        this.myvalue = value;
    }

    public int GetValue ( )
    {
        return this.myvalue;
    }
}

public class PassGeneric
{
    public void AcceptsGeneric ( Enum<? extends MyInterface> generic_enum )
    {
        generic_enum.values();                                 // Not valid
        generic_enum.GetValue();                               // Not valid
        generic_enum.getDeclaringClass().getEnumConstants();   // Valid
        ((Enum<?>)generic_enum).values();                      // Not Valid
        ((MyInterface)generic_enum).GetValue();                // Valid
    }
}
```

I'm just trying to understand why the type specifier `Enum<? extends MyInterface>` does not allow me to 1) directly access the `MyInterface` methods, and 2) directly access the Enum methods such as `.values()`.

Casting works for accessing the `MyInterface` methods, but to me defeats the purpose of specifying that the generic type extends `MyInterface` since it's still legal to just replace `Enum<? extends MyInterface>` with `Enum<?>` and cast the object as `(MyInterface)`.

If i've misinterpreted the use of generics and implementing `extends` could someone explain to me how to correctly explicitly specify a generic implements a given interface.

Comment: Is there any reason you would just use `MyInterface` as the parameter?

Comment: Because I also want to access the enum methods such as `.values()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access `values()` because it's not an instance method; it's a static method belonging to the enum type. So passing an instance of the superclass `Enum` doesn't give you the information you need.

As far as the interface methods, declaring `Enum<? extends MyInterface>` declared certain generic information about the *enum*, but doesn't tell the compiler that `generic_enum` is itself an instance of `MyInterface`.

If you want to declare that `generic_enum` implements `MyInterface`, you should do exactly that:

```
public void AcceptsGeneric ( MyInterface generic_enum )
```

If, for whatever reason, you need to know that it implements `MyInterface` *and* it's an enum, you can declare your method as follows:

```
public <T extends Enum<T> & MyInterface> void AcceptsGeneric ( T generic_enum )
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a generic parameter on `Enum`?

Answer (score 0):

Declaring the parameter of the method as `Enum<? extends MyInterface> generic_enum` restricts methods of `generic_enum` you can access without a cast to the methods of [`Enum`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html). The type argument doesn't change the type to something other than `Enum`. Therefore these lines are not valid:

```
generic_enum.values();
generic_enum.GetValue();
((Enum<?>)generic_enum).values(); // ((Enum<?>)generic_enum) still of type Enum
```

Now let's look at the following line:

```
((MyInterface)generic_enum).GetValue();
```

There's no reason to not allow the cast. Classes extending `Enum` can implement `MyInterface`. Therefore there is no reason to disallow that cast. (The compiler doesn't disallow this, just because a `ClassCastException` could happen at runtime).

Now the remaining line:

```
generic_enum.getDeclaringClass().getEnumConstants();
```

Because `generic_enum` is of type `Enum<? extends MyInterface>`, the return type of `generic_enum.getDeclaringClass()` is `Class<? extends MyInterface>`. Since `Class` contains a method `getEnumConstants()` the line is valid.

Since you can still access the values from the class of `generic_enum`, you can declare `AcceptsGeneric` as

```
public void AcceptsGeneric(MyInterface generic_enum)
```

or

```
public<T extends Enum<T> & MyInterface> void AcceptsGeneric(T generic_enum)
```

and use

```
generic_enum.getClass().getEnumConstants()
```

to get the values.